# How to get on scroll events?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, scrollbar

I need to get scroll events from a div with overflow: scroll in my Angular 2 app.

It seems [onscroll event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) do not works on Angular 2.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Quite often you can apply events that as onclick, onsubmit etc. In angular the equivalent is usually just removing the 'on' and adding () from event names. e.g (click), (submit) etc... :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75073987/3099784

Answer (score 219, accepted):

```
// @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) // for scroll events of the current element
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // for window scroll events
onScroll(event) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)"></div>
```

Comment: (scroll)="onScroll($event)" solved my problem well. Do you know if there's a equivalent binding to onresize of a element?

Comment: No, browsers don't provide events for resize of elements, only for window resize (`'window:resize'`). You could implement `ngDoCheck()` and poll the size there. This can be expensive though, therefore if you can rely on less frequent events for polling the size using such an event instead would be preferred.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you tell from the event which direction the scroll is going? That is without examining and comparing the div scrollY value to the previous?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll lists the information provided by the event, which doesn't include anything about direction.

Comment: In addition, This one is worked in Angular 6 --> stackoverflow.com/a/42547136/621951

Comment: @GünayGültekin this one is to listen to scroll evens from an element, the one you linked to is for scroll events of the page/window.

Comment: @Dmitry Grinko you don't always want window scroll events. Often you want scroll events from the current component. For example if you build a scrollable list or table component.

Comment: How to listen to an element scroll or "scrollTop" of an element? For example in a directive. Instead of "window". Window scroll only works on the body html scroll.

Comment: See the last line in my answer above ;-)

Comment: However, is hostlistener the best to use? HostListener leads to excessive change detection as mentioned here. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16986 
I do see a performance impact by using hostlistener, is not another way?

Comment: @jcdsr without diving deeper into the issue and it's a long time ago I answered - usually you want change detection after an event, the main issue is the high frequency of scroll events (or resize events). If you use rxjs, you can use rate limiting and stuff which you can't with `@HostListener()`

Answer (score 44):

You could use a @HostListener decorator. Works with Angular 4 and up.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener("window:scroll", []) onWindowScroll() {
    // do some stuff here when the window is scrolled
    const verticalOffset = window.pageYOffset 
          || document.documentElement.scrollTop 
          || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
}
```

Comment: How does setting a constant to a set of or statements work?

Comment: @SirPapilonius the first one that's not falsy (0 or undefined etc.) will be used as the value.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Ah, of course, that makes sense. Didn't think of that. Clever!

Comment: HostListener leads to excessive change detection as mentioned here. github.com/angular/angular/issues/16986 I do see a performance impact by using hostlistener, is not another way?

Answer (score 36):

for angular 4, the working solution was to do inside the component

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){
  console.log($event);
  console.log("scrolling");
}
```

Comment: Hello, i just used your code in my component and last i added a (scroll)="onScrollEvent($event)" but i doesn't work.

Comment: (scroll)="onScrollEvent($event)" doesn't work, but my code is currently working on angular version 4.0.0, It triggers the scroll event

Comment: this works fine, no need to add `(scroll)="onScrollEvent($event)` in the HTML with this.

Comment: HostListener leads to excessive change detection as mentioned here. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16986 
I do see a performance impact by using hostlistener, is not another way?

Answer (score 20):

Listen to `window:scroll` event for window/document level scrolling and element's `scroll` event for element level scrolling.

### window:scroll

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll($event) {

}
```

or

```
<div (window:scroll)="onWindowScroll($event)">
```

### scroll

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onElementScroll($event) {

}
```

or

```
<div (scroll)="onElementScroll($event)">
```

`@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])` won't work if the host element itself is not scroll-able.

### Examples

- [Using Event Binding](https://plnkr.co/edit/jZEmvMVAJ0XoU0eL6dgp)
- [Using HostListener](https://plnkr.co/edit/5cs8oMraePEos0xEJbh8)

Comment: remember to add import:
`import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: ```<div (window:scroll)="onWindowScroll($event)">```, clear, easy and works like a charm for me. Thanks mate!

Comment: HostListener leads to excessive change detection as mentioned here. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16986 
I do see a performance impact by using hostlistener, is not another way?

Answer (score 14):

Alternative to `@HostListener` and scroll output on the element I would suggest using [fromEvent](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent) from RxJS since you can chain it with `filter()` and `distinctUntilChanges()` and can easily skip *flood* of potentially redundant events (and change detections).

Here is a simple example:

```js
// {static: true} can be omitted if you don't need this element/listener in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('elementId', {static: true}) el: ElementRef;

// ...

fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'scroll')
  .pipe(
    // Is elementId scrolled for more than 50 from top?
    map((e: Event) => (e.srcElement as Element).scrollTop > 50),
    // Dispatch change only if result from map above is different from previous result
    distinctUntilChanged());
```

Answer (score 4):

To capture scroll events and see which of the scroll event is being called, you have to use host listener who will observe the scroll behavior and then this thing will be detected in the function below the host listener.

```
currentPosition = window.pageYOffset;
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event.target']) // for window scroll events
scroll(e) {
  let scroll = e.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  console.log("this is the scroll position", scroll)
  if (scroll > this.currentPosition) {
    console.log("scrollDown");
  } else {
    console.log("scrollUp");
  }
  this.currentPosition = scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## wheel event

Try (in my case `scroll` event not works)

```js
<div (wheel)="onScroll($event)"></div>
```

Comment: This solved it for me. If you are not actually scrolling through the page and only want to intercept the scrolling action, then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check the multiple examples as mention on this URL.

I will recommend the method 3,

https://itnext.io/4-ways-to-listen-to-page-scrolling-for-dynamic-ui-in-angular-ft-rxjs-5a83f91ee487

```
    @Component({
        selector       : 'ngx-root',
        templateUrl    : './app.component.html',
        styleUrls      : [ './app.component.scss' ],
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
        
        destroy = new Subject();
        
            destroy$ = this.destroy.asObservable();
        
        constructor() {
            fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
                .subscribe((e: Event) => console.log(this.getYPosition(e)));
            }
        
            getYPosition(): number {
            return (e.target as Element).scrollTop;
            }

        ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.destroy.next();
        }
        
    }
```

However Method 4 is not bad.