# Angular: listen scroll event on parent's component?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have 2 components:

Parent's template:

```
<div #scrollable style="overflow: scroll">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Use case:

```
 <parent>
     <child></child>
 </parent>
```

What would be an "angular", decoupled way of listening to `scroll` event of `#scrollable` div, but inside `<child></child>` component?

AFAIK `@HostListener` won't be able to target `#scrollable`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Implement an interface that your child will implement :

```js
interface ScrollableParent {
  parentOnScroll(event: MouseScrollEvent);
}
```

Then use a template variable on your child selector to trigger the function from the parent template :

```html
<parent (scroll)="child.parentOnScroll($event)">
  <child #child></child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks, any suggestion for case, where children are spawned within ngFor?

Comment: Sure, use `@ViewChildren` to get the children in your component, and use `(scroll)="someFunction($event)"`, where the function does something like `this.children.forEach(child => child.parentOnScroll(event))`

Comment: Tried it and `@ViewChildrent` doesn't work with `ng-content`. Had to use `@ContentChildren(MyDir, {descendants: true})`. But then, `MyDir` is not able to access the host component, where I need to invoke scroll handler. The host is simply not reachable by giving it an interface, so I can't invoke `onParentScroll` on `undefined`. Now, is this it or anything else I can try?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] reproducing that? I'll get my hands dirty, this will be easier than making assumptions

Comment: Sure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhidjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: You simply forgot to tell your decorator what you are reading. Try with `@ContentChildren(ScrollReceiveDirective, {descendants: true, read: ChildComponent})`, [as you can see working here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxhjce?file=src/app/parent.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it works, but couples components. My problem is that those parent and child comps are in different modules, and they should stay like that and work without each other too.

Comment: I have updated [the blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxhjce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts) with a working solution. The fact is that your query list is a list of directive instances, and you didn't declare the function in the directive. Once declared, as you can see, it works like a charm (I have made a console log for you to see the type of list it is)

Comment: Thank you for your effort! However, this is not what I'm after, I need to trigger `onScroll()` method inside the `child.component`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxhjce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: You won't be able to, I'm sorry : to call a method from a child, you need to know the class of that child. It's because Angualr relies on weak maps to fetch the injected components : if you provide the exact class in the constructor, Angular will inject the child. But unfortunately, you can't use interfaces for that. You could maybe try with the injectors, but that would be overkill for that ...

Answer (score 3):

You can actually listen to the scroll event through a **Directive's HostListener**

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scroll-directive) for your reference. Check the console section for the console logs emitted from the example.

**AppDirective**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[listenScroll]'
})
export class AppDirective {

  // This will emit the scroll update to whatever you want to assign with its emitted value
  @Output() windowScroll: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])           // Listens to Window Scroll Event
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.windowScroll.next('scrolled');       // Use the @Output() windowScroll to emit a simple string 'scrolled' whenever the window triggers a scroll event from the user
  }

}
```

**ParentComponent**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <div listenScroll                                     // Our directive attached to the element
          (windowScroll)="isScrolled$.next('scrolled')">   // Since the directive has been attached, we can also call and use its windowScroll @Output event emitted from the directive itself that we had created.

        <child [scrollUpdate]="isScrolled$"></child>   // Add an input [] scrollUpdate bracket to the ChildComponent to subscribe to whatever scroll event that its parent listens and passes to

     </div>
  `,
  styles: [`div { height: 200vh; }`]
})
export class AppComponent  { 

  isScrolled$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();     We use a RxJS Subject as it is a continuous event that we want to subscribe to dynamically

}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<div>I am a child</div>`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() scrollUpdate: string;      // It stores here whatever the scroll event update that its parent has passed in to

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Listens and Subscribes to the latest emitted value from @Input() which its value is dependent from the parent's directive scroll update 
    this.scrollUpdate.subscribe(val => console.log('Child: ', val));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, below solution is the simplest / robust / comply with all conditions. Since, addEventListener is plain js.

```
    const scroller = document.querySelector(".wrapper-element");

    scroller?.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
      if(scroller?.scrollTop > 300){//You can define<300> as per requirement.
        this.windowScrolled = true;
      } else{
        this.windowScrolled = false;
      }
    });
```

Now using this, you are aware of either the element scrolled or not. This element could exist anywhere in the DOM, no restrictions of parent / child.

And you can also decide your scrolling volume. One down scroll = value 100.