# Getting the scroll position for an Angular component

Tags: angular

How can I get the scroll position with a component with fromEvent?

I use this to get mouse position, how do I get scroll from top position?

```
this.mouseMoveSubscription = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove')
                  .subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {...});
```

This doesn't work:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.scrollSubscription = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scroll')
                  .subscribe((e: Scroll) => {
                    console.log(e.position);
                  });

  }
```

No events are firing for this either (from: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41304986/11883991)):

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) // for scroll events of the current element
onScroll(event) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does your element have scroll bar? Try to subscribe to the element that has scrollbar, for example: `fromEvent(document.body, 'scroll')`.

Comment: it has a scroll bar, and I need to get the scroll position of the component not the window which doesn't have a scroll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're just looking for the position in the wrong event attribute.

```js
fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'scroll')
      .subscribe((e: Event) => console.log({
        scrollPosition: e.target['scrollTop']
        }));
```

Take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57448849?file=src/app/app.component.css).