# Angular 10 - How to auto load new items when collection changes

Tags: angular

The idea is that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page it should add more items.
I'm adding more items to the *posts* variable in the onScroll() method, but I can't figure out how the html template will auto load the new items.

**home-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  templateUrl: './home-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-component.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  numbers(n: number): number[] {
    return [...Array(n).keys()];
  }
  page: number = 1;
  posts: Post[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
      let imgNo = ((2 * i) % 3) + 1;
      let p = new Post;
      p.userName = "username" + i;
      p.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
      p.postImageURL = "../assets/images/post" + imgNo + ".png";
      p.postMessage = "message for the post " + i + "...";
      p.noOfLikes = 2 * i;
      this.posts.push(p);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onScroll() {
    //this.page++;
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      let imgNo = ((2 * i) % 3) + 1;
      let p = new Post;
      p.userName = "username" + i;
      p.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
      p.postImageURL = "../assets/images/post" + imgNo + ".png";
      p.postMessage = "message for the post " + i + "...";
      p.noOfLikes = 2 * i;
      this.posts.push(p);
    }
  }
}
```

**home-component.component.html**

```
<span *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <post-component [userName]="post.userName"
                  [profileIconURL]="post.profileIconURL"
                  [postImageURL]="post.postImageURL"
                  [postMessage]="post.postMessage"
                  [noOfLikes]="post.noOfLikes"
  >
  </post-component>
</span>
```

Comment: You can use the power of rxjs observables and Angular async pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304968/how-to-get-on-scroll-events) helped.

home-component.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-component',
  templateUrl: './home-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-component.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  numbers(n: number): number[] {
    return [...Array(n).keys()];
  }
  page: number = 1;
  posts: Post[] = [];
  subject: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  array$: Observable<any> =  this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      let imgNo = ((2 * i) % 3) + 1;
      let p = new Post;
      p.userName = "username" + i;
      p.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
      p.postImageURL = "../assets/images/post" + imgNo + ".png";
      p.postMessage = "message for the post " + i + "...";
      p.noOfLikes = 2 * i;
      //this.posts.push(p);
      this.addElementToObservableArray(p);
      console.log(i);
    }
  }

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent(event: any){
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304968/how-to-get-on-scroll-events

  let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  let scrolltop = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
  let max = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  let windowheight = window.innerHeight;
  let isbottom = scrolltop + windowheight == max;
  let istop = scrolltop == 0;
  console.log(pos + "," + max + "," + document.documentElement.offsetHeight + "," + scrolltop);

   if(isbottom )   {
      //console.log("End");
      this.page++;
      console.log(this.page);
      for (let i = this.page; i < this.page+5; i++) {
        let imgNo = ((2 * i) % 3) + 1;
        let p = new Post;
        p.userName = "username" + i;
        p.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
        p.postImageURL = "../assets/images/post" + imgNo + ".png";
        p.postMessage = "message for post " + i + "...";
        p.noOfLikes = 2 * i;
        //this.posts.push(p);
        this.addElementToObservableArray(p);
      }
 }
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addElementToObservableArray(item) {
    this.array$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val)
      const newArr = [...val, item];
      this.subject.next(newArr);
    })
  }
}
```

home-component.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let post of array$ | async">
  <app-post-component [userName]="post.userName"
                  [profileIconURL]="post.profileIconURL"
                  [postImageURL]="post.postImageURL"
                  [postMessage]="post.postMessage"
                  [noOfLikes]="post.noOfLikes"
  >
  </app-post-component>
</div>
```

post-component.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-component',
  templateUrl: './post-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-component.component.css']
})
export class PostComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() userName: string;
  @Input() profileIconURL: string;
  @Input() postImageURL: string;
  @Input() postMessage: string;
  @Input() noOfLikes;
  @Input() comments;

  @Input() post: any;

  constructor() {
    this.userName = "Test user";
    this.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
    this.postImageURL = "../assets/images/postdefault.png";
    this.noOfLikes = 0;
    this.postMessage = "post message...";
    this.comments = "";
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

post-component.component.html

```
<div class="container text-center py-4" style="width:480px;">
  <div class="card bg-white rounded border bg-primary">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 text-left ml-2"><img src="{{profileIconURL}}" width="48"></div>
      <div class="col-md-7 text-left justify-content-left d-flex align-items-center p-0">{{userName}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mr-2">
        <div class="float-right">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" style="height:400px;"><img src="{{postImageURL}}" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-left ml-2">{{noOfLikes}} Likes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-left ml-2">{{postMessage}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

post.ts

```
export class Post {
  id: number;
  userName: string;
  profileIconURL: string;
  postImageURL: string;
  postMessage: string;
  noOfLikes: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.userName = "Test user";
    this.profileIconURL = "../assets/images/dp.png";
    this.postImageURL = "../assets/images/postdefault.png";
    this.noOfLikes = 0;
    this.postMessage = "braydoncoyer I can't wait to see the new Star Wars movie.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the rxjs observables or you can use the change detection strategies for letting the HTML know that the data has changed.

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from @angular/core
...

constructor (private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
..

onListLoad() {
... Loading algorithm
this.cdRef.detectChanges()
}
```

This is how you can use this. Change Detector would inform the HTML page that it has to reload itself.

You can also read more about the Virtual scrolling in Angular which handles it more graciously and also manages the load over DOM at all the times. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/codetobe/learn-how-to-us-virtual-scrolling-in-angular-7-51158dcacbd4) that can help you with it.

Comment: I got it to working. I'll post my answer soon. But I'll check the article to learn ideas. Thanks.