# How to change angular material toolbar background-color to white after scrolling and transparent in start?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying change the background color of toolbar to white on scroll using angular material.

```html
<mat-toolbar class="main-container" color="primary">
 <div fxHide.gt-sm>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="onToggleSidenav()">
    <mat-icon class="menu-toggle">menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="logo-area">
  <a routerLink="/"><img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo/logo-main.svg" alt=""></a>
 </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

get the element in ts file using -

```
<mat-toolbar class="main-container" #templateRefName color="primary">
@ViewChild('templateRefName') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }
```

and add listener -

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll($event) {
    console.log("scrolling...");
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I guess I have questioned the wrong question. the question should be: How to change angular material toolbar background-color to white after scrolling?

Comment: @aboutbenjamin try this this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', '#fff !mportant');

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scroll event fired by the window. Check this answer:
[How to get on scroll events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304968/how-to-get-on-scroll-events)

Comment: How to change angular material toolbar background-color to white after scrolling?