# Show a navbar when scroll down Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, navbar

I want to display a div that contains a navbar when I scroll down. Knowing that on the page I have a power bi report embeded
html :

```
<div class="divNav " (scroll)="onWindowScroll($event)">
...
</div>
<div class="report">
  <iframe  [src]="this.linkReport" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

css:

```
other class ...
    .scroll-down
    {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

ts:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e) {
    let menu = document.querySelector(".divNav");
    let scrollDown = "scroll-down";
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      if (currentScroll > 100) {
        menu.classList.add(scrollDown);
        return;
      }
    })
```

}

Comment: What does the CSS look like for `.divNav`?

Comment: .divNav
{
  alignment: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Din;
  z-index: 5;

}

Answer (score 0):

I think HostListener is already the event handler.
I thik currently you add an Eventlistener each time a scroll event is fired?
try:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event) {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      if (currentScroll > 100) {
        let menu = document.querySelector(".divNav");
        menu.classList.add("scroll-down");
      }
    })
```

Comment: I update my code like you told me. It doesn't work

Comment: hmm sometimes pageYOffset is not what you want.
Maybe try this:

    const verticalOffset = window.pageYOffset 
          || document.documentElement.scrollTop 
          || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

and have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304968/how-to-get-on-scroll-events

Comment: I had already tried the solution proposed in this discussion but it didn't work. The fact that I scroll in a power bi report and not a normal page has no impact?

Comment: hmm if you are actually scrolling inside the iframe i dont think there is a chance to make it work because of the sandbox. but i am only sure that you should not get any scroll events? did you ever console.log in the the onWindowScroll?

Comment: sorry for my late answer. I'm already blocked about this subject. In the console I had this message : This site seems to use a positioning effect related to scrolling. This effect may not work properly with asynchronous scrolling. See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for more details or to discuss related tools and features.

Comment: I also tried to use the function inside the iframe and it doesn't work. When I use a console.log inside my function I have nothing in the console any solutions guys please?