# Angular: undesired window.scroll trigger at page load

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, scroll

**Desired outcome:** call method `sendNotification()` when a component first gets into view as the user scrolls down.

**My solution (code follows):**

1. Listen for window:scroll as learned reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304968/how-to-get-on-scroll-events) question
2. Doing some calculations to check if the element is in view
3. Calling the method

```js
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  hintSent: boolean = false

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _notificationService: NotificationsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let elem: Element = this._elementRef.nativeElement
    let top = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
    let height = elem.getBoundingClientRect().height
    let noti = new Notification('Tocca le immagini','Scopri altri dettagli sul nostro prodotto interagendo con le immagini')
    if(top - window.innerHeight < 0 && top + height - window.innerHeight > 0)
      //this component is in view
      if(this.hintSent == false)
        this._notificationService.sendNotification(noti)
        this.hintSent = true
  }
}
```

**The problem with my solution:**

While angular renders the page the layout shift triggers the scroll event and calls the desired method before time since the user has not scrolled down yet. Now I could start listening for the scroll after a timeout or after the document.loaded event but is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you checked if attaching that listener in a `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook still causes the issue?

Comment: Does this imply dropping the @HostListener and using a regular listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your listener once you know your element has been created in view, hence in the lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit`. Your nativeelement may be wrong or not even exist before that.